# Problema con Recycler View + CardView + OnCreate en Android

Tags: android, recyclerview, cardview

**En mi codigo no me marca ningun error**

Según tengo problemas con el init pero por mas vueltas que le doy no encuentro cual puede ser el problema soy nuevo en esto también cabe recalcar, tengo adjuntado en el gradle las librerias y sincronizadas tengo otras dos clases java donde tengo el listAdapter.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
List<ListElement> elements;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();
}

public void init() {
    elements = new ArrayList<>();
    elements.add(new ListElement("#775447","Gustavo","Chiapas","Activo"));
    elements.add(new ListElement("#772447","Eduardo","Guatemala","Nulo"));
    elements.add(new ListElement("#725447","Jared","Guasave","Inac"));
    elements.add(new ListElement("#785447","Juan","Zacatecas","Inactivo"));
    elements.add(new ListElement("#720447","Ivan","Obregon","Cancelar"));


    ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(elements, this);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listRecyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

}

Comment: Al compilar estos son los errores que me arroja                                                          at com.example.recyclerviewcard.MainActivity.init(MainActivity.java:34)
at com.example.recyclerviewcard.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)

Comment: Crees que puedas añadir todo el error que te da AS? Por lo que veo la linea 34 es `RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listRecyclerView);` Lo primero que se me viene a la mente es que el `id` no es el correcto o no esté en el `R.layout.activity_main`.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.recyclerviewcard, PID: 31713
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.recyclerviewcard/com.example.recyclerviewcard.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

Comment: `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` Checa el `id` que le estás asignando al `RecyclerView` es el incorrecto, `listRecyclerView` le pertenece a un `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Exacto le pertenece al ConstraintLayout que es mi activity_main.xml pero se supone que coloque el id a este constraint y es el que necesito mandar a llamar.

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer es referenciar un `RecyclerView` con la vista, que el cual también debe ser un `RecyclerView` en el `xml`. Crees que puedas compartir todo tu `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: `<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/listRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">`

Comment: `<TextView
        android:id="@+id/TitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Lista"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />`

Comment: `<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.034"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout> Si exactamente`

Comment: Vale. Añade un `id` dentro de `<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` y usa ese mismo en `RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.<new_id>);`. Solo reemplaza <new_id> con el nuevo `id`.

Comment: Tengo dos clases java con el mainActivity un listElement donde tengo los constructor y mis setter y un list adapter donde creo los metodos y al final con el codigo del mainActivity ejecuto lo del listAdapter

Comment: Genial muchas gracias ese era el problema te agradezco demasiado y gracias por tu tiempo ese era el problema si gustas puedes ponerlo como respuesta para validar @favs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale. Parece que el `id` en `RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listRecyclerView);` le pertenece a otra vista. Asegúrate que el `id` del `RecyclerView` sea el mismo en tu `activity_main.xml` y en el `findViewById`.